# Remove [ character from a text file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How can I remove the `[` character from a text file?

My text file contains lines like this:

```
[Adminlogin] 172.16.48.131 Wednesday Jan102018 07:05:36
```

And I would like to remove the `[`.

When I run this,

```
$file = "MyFile.txt"
Get-Content $file  | Foreach {$_ -replace "[", ""}  | Set-Content "Myfile-1.txt"
```

I get an error

> The regular expression pattern [ is not valid

However when I run this to remove the `]`,

```
$file = "MyFile.txt"
Get-Content $file  | Foreach {$_ -replace "]", ""}  | Set-Content "Myfile-1.txt"
```

It runs with no problem.

Comment: Done and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` is a regular expression meta character, so you need to escape it.

The simplest way is to use:

```
{$ -replace "\[", ""}
```

Or you can use the `[Regex]::Escape($str)` method. See blog post *[PowerShell Tip - Escape Regex MetaCharacters](http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2014/09/powershell-tip-escape-regex.html)* for a more detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
Foreach {$_ -replace '[', ""}
```

Should also work.